# Is there any tool which can control subversion by a browser?

Tags: svn, web-applications, browser, command

Since I am a Japanese, I am poor at English. 
Although I feel sorry in poor English, I need your help well.

I would like to be able to execute the command of subversion(s), such as commit, lock, and unlock, briefly to Subversion using a browser. 
As the reason, using - thin client, since there are many users, execution of the command of subversion cannot be directly carried out from client PC. 
- It cannot perform except exe which is not permitted because of a thin client. 
- Since there is no administrator authority at a thin client, an add-on cannot be put in to a browser, either. 
Although I expect whether to become the application which probably operates on a server, does such application exist?

Answer (score 2):

There is a community question that is similar to yours: [What is the best web based Subversion client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137540/what-is-the-best-web-based-subversion-client). I would like to add a few remarks, so hopefully, the duplication is tolerable:

- If you want to work with Subversion (adding / changing / removing content), the model is that you have a local checkout location on your PC or workstation. Therefore, a pure web client for all aspects of Subversion is not possible.
- However, there are aspects that could be possible through a web interface (without checking out locally)

  - Changing directly in the repository. For that, you need a subversion client installed like TortoiseSVN on Windows. Or you find some candidate in the list above.
  - Administration of (parts of) the repository. This could be possible through a web interface if your Subversion server supports that. Get in touch with your System Administrator if that is what you want to do.
- Subversion allows to use WebDAV as an interface. So you don't have to install anything, but connect to your repository by the WebDAV protocol. See for example [WebDAV and Autoversioning](http://oreilly.com/opensource/excerpts/9780596510336/webdav-and-autoversioning.html) how to connect depending on your OS.

But to really work with Subversion, you will need a real client.